# how to reduce server git repo size when delete a branch

Tags: git, github

I have use gitlabhq configed a git server. 
All Repos save in `/repos/` directory at server.

I have a project, and have a branch, this branch have big files.
For save disk space, i delete this branch use `git push origin :test`.

But when i go to my git server, found this project repo size not change.

So my questions is how to  reduce server git repo size when delete a branch?

I have used git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -f bigfile.zip' HEAD, also seems can not
reduce server git repo size.

Comment: GC and repack on the server. Although if the commits are still reachable, you're probably SOL.

Comment: can you tell me the command of detail about git GC and repack?

Comment: `git help gc` and `git help repack`. If you have more specific questions, ask those.

Comment: my question is when goto  your project git directory in server.```cd /repos/grant/test.git/``` run which command can delete the branch to reduce the directory(```/repos/grant/test.git```) size?

Comment: Did you try what has been suggested here? What worked? What didn't work? Did you make sure to remove all references to the branch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have resolved it by run below command in server.

`bash
git gc --aggressive --prune=now`

Comment: Hi, I have 3 types of branches 1) local which are also on remote, 2) local which are not on remote, 3) branches which i have deleted from local. I only want to clear space of the branches which i have deleted. will this command only delete "3" and not 2 ?

Answer (score 2):

Delete all references to it (including from HEAD's reflog), then do `git gc`.

As far as I know, this is not available from `git push` and should be done on server.